# Parsing string into date, Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

I have a date string stored in DB, as shown below

```
20180502160645
```

I want to parse it in this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

Tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date date = dateParser.parse(dateString);
def parsedDate = dateParser.format(date);
```

And this:

```
Date dateTest = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",dateString );
```

Both failed to parse it.

Answer (score 3):

Using the following format (below) will match the input:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def dateString = '20180502160645'

SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
Date date = dateParser.parse(dateString);
def parsedDate = dateParser.format(date);
assert dateString == parsedDate
```

Comment: Here is the same code in the Groovy Web Console: if you click 'edit in console', then 'execute script', it works. So something must be different for you, buddy. Possibly reading from the database? - https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5144942464729088

Comment: use dateParser to parse the string, and create a new SimpleDateFormat object to format the date object to your desired format